# Including Files(dll, txt etc.) in .exe Application in C++

Tags: c++, file, dll, include, exe

I made a program written in C++ that uses many files, like .dll or .png.
The program and the files are in the same directory.
Is it possible including files in the .exe application?
So that I only need the .exe file to run the program.

Comment: Depending on what framework you use you may be able to add the png files to the executable. The dlls you can not add without having to extract somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, yes.  The answer is writing all the files you need, contained in a zip file, at the end of the executable you're running.  Here's how: [Part 1](http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/2354/how-to-write-a-self-extractor-for-the-windows-os) (writing to the executable) and <strike>[Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354553/c-lightweight-library-for-reading-zip-files)</strike> [broken link] (reading from the executable).  It's fun stuff; good question.

Note that you *can't* do this for DLL files - they must either be in the same directory as the executable or installed on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question and answer.

I did it a long time ago by putting all the files inside the .exe as resources, and then extracting them all using the following procedure:

```
HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_RESOURCE_ID), MY_RESOURCE_TYPE);
HGLOBAL hRes = LoadResource(NULL, hResInfo)
LPVOID lpData = LockResource(hRes);
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(....)
WriteFile(hFile, lpData, SizeOfResource(NULL, hResInfo), ...);
CloseHandle(hFile)
```

The problem with my implementation was that I had to recompile the .exe everytime a new file was added (which happened only once or twice, luckily), but it's good to know how does it work under the hood.

Comment: That's a more straightforward approach, but resource files are hard to manage if you don't have the Pro Edition of Visual Studio.